# What does の頃【ころ】 mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, particles

I don't know what の頃【ころ】 means in this sentence. I know ころ means 'about' or 'around' but I still don't understand its use here.

ロンドンに来たばかりの頃【ころ】、私は「Chip Butty」を知りませんでした。

My best translation:

I've just come back from london and I didn't know what a Chip Butty was.

Comment: 2 things: 1) There are both ころ and ごろ. "Around X o'clock" is ごろ, not ころ. 2) The speaker is in or around London as he says that sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ころ` means "around", "about", or "(at) the time".  So it translates to:

> At the time I'd just come <strike>back</strike> to London, ...

Note that it's `come to London`, not `come back from London`.

Other common usages include

> - 子供のころ　→　When I was a child
> - 高校生のころ　→　When I was in high school

Comment: I didn't know the 'at the time' meaning so thanks. What would 'just come back from london' be then, maybe - 'ロンドンに来たからばかり'?

Comment: "Just come back from London" would be `ロンドンから帰ってきたばかり`.