# Understanding トムは高校生のころ拒食症になった。

Tags: translation, particles

The sentence

> トムは高校生のころ拒食症になった。

apparently translates to

> Tom became anorexic when he was a high school student.

My confusion is how the phrases

> 高校生のころ

and

> 拒食症

grammatically fit into the sentence.

1. Is に marking the entire phrase 高校生のころ拒食症, so that the sentence parsing is something like this:

> トムは((高校生のころ)(拒食症))になった?

2. Is 高校生のころ an adjectival phrase modifying 拒食症? If not, what is 高校生のころ classified as? And why doesn't it have its own particle marking it?

Comment: Certain phrases such as ～ころに, ときに, ために can have their ni dropped especially in formal speech (no that is not a typo). Also it's an adverbial phrase modifying the entire following clause

Comment: Are you saying in this case that (高校生のころ) could have a に placed at the end of it (but it was dropped)? If this is true, this sentence would have two に's; is that an issue?

Comment: There is no problem with the sentence having two nis, no

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence ころ is used as "when", so the parsing is
トムは(高校生のころ)(拒食症になった)?

Smth like "Tome became anorexic when a high school student"

So, it's a separate clause if you like.

Can't resist putting unrelated quote from Three in a boat "... and wish I'd been kinder to my little sister when a boy"

Also see here [What does の頃【ころ】 mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/what-does-%e3%81%ae%e9%a0%83-%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d-mean-in-this-sentence) , it seems it' especially common usage with high school for some reason